# Prove a graph $(V,E)$ with $d$-maximal degree let $k=d/2+1$ can be decomposed as $V=V_1 \cup\cdots \cup V_k$ where each $V_i$ is a loopless graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I tried looking at a vertex v with the maximal degree, that is $d(v)=d$ and started looking at it's neighbours
$$N(v):=\{u\mid (u,v) \in E\}$$
therefore $|N(v)|=d$, now between every two vertice $z,w\in N(v)$ 
Where are no cycle so you can devide the nieghbour group into $d/2$ subgroups, 
now I get stuck with the other $V-\{v\}-N(v)$ vertices and I was trying to somehow put then into these groups but got stuck.
Help anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking long and hard about it and I realised that induction can be applied:
for n=3 It's obvious we have three vertice $ v_1 , v_2, v_3 $
Highest possible degree here could be 2 so:
$ V_1=v_1 $ $V_2$={$v_2, v_3$}

Suppose that the claim is true for all m where m < n:
Let'a look at our G=(V,E) where |V|=n.
Take a vertex $ v\in V $ such v has the minimal degree so we know that d(v)<=d.
If we now look at V-{v} this graph has m=n-1 vertices and still has maximal degree of d (we didn't delete the vertex with the maximal degree) therefore by induction where's a decomposition into k=d/2+1 disjoint vertice group. Now if the v we removed closes a cycle in each of $ V_1, V_2,..., V_k $ it must be that it has at least 2 edges going into each component whereby it has to have at least 2k edges meaning d(v)>2k-1=d+1 but we don't have that many edges (bouded by d edges max degree) so where exists a component $V_j$ such that v joined with it doesn't close a cycle, so none of the groups have a cycle and where is exactly k disjoint vertice groups as such.

Comment: That's easy to fix, but currently your proof is not valid, if you remove some vertex, you also remove edges incident to it, hence you could possibly reduce the maximum degree.

Comment: then would it be possible to devide into two cases:

1. the v we removed didn't touch the maximal degree, so the proof above works.
2. the $ v_min $ with the minimal degree did touch the $ v_max $ v with the maximal degree so highest degree now could be d-1 therefore by induction where are k=(d-1)/2 + 1 such groups and I think in that case we could just take points and add them such that they sum to d/2+1 groups.
It's just that we did not go over  the nash-williams theorem in class therefore unfortunetly I can not use it.

Comment: What if the theorem used "at most $k$" rather than "exactly $k$"? You can always add some empty sets later ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Nash-Williams arboricity theorem (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arboricity)), in particular, for any subgraph $H \subseteq G$ we have

\begin{align*}
  \left\lceil\frac{|E_H|}{|V_H|-1}\right\rceil
  &= \left\lceil \frac{\frac{1}{2}\sum_{v \in V_H}\deg_H(v)}{|V_H|-1}\right\rceil \\
  &\leq \left\lceil \frac{\frac{1}{2}d_H\big(|V_H|-1\big)+\frac{1}{2}d_H}{|V_H|-1}\right\rceil \\
  &\leq  \left\lceil \frac{1}{2}d_H + \frac{1}{2}\right\rceil
  &\leq k 
\end{align*}
where $\displaystyle d_H = \max_{v \in V_H}\deg_H(v)$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

This shows what happens when we removed the minimal vertex and it had an edge touching the maximal degree:
[image]